# How to set OnClickListiner on Navigation Items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am developing an app in which I included navigation and sliding both. But in navigation, I am not able to where I need to write for click on listener so that when I click on that navigation part items,it will respond.
Below is my code:

```
    private void init_navigator(){
        // Navigation Drawer
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_DrawerLayout);
        mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryDark));
        mScrimInsetsFrameLayout = (ScrimInsetsFrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_navigation_drawer_rootLayout);

        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle
                (
                        this,
                        mDrawerLayout,
                        toolbar,
                        R.string.navigation_drawer_opened,
                        R.string.navigation_drawer_closed
                )

        {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
            {
                // Disables the burger/arrow animation by default
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, 0);
            }
        };


        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null)
        {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        // Navigation Drawer layout width
        int possibleMinDrawerWidth = UtilsDevice.getScreenWidth(this) -
                UtilsMiscellaneous.getThemeAttributeDimensionSize(this, android.R.attr.actionBarSize);
        int maxDrawerWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.navigation_drawer_max_width);

        mScrimInsetsFrameLayout.getLayoutParams().width = Math.min(possibleMinDrawerWidth, maxDrawerWidth);
        // Set the first item as selected for the first time
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.toolbar_title_home);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement this interface in activity

```
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

Add this in oncreate

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Handle below part of code in you activity

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();
     switch(id){
     case R.id.settings:
     break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you using for navigation itemlist: Listview,recyclerview or simply showing the item label using string array.?
post code for itemlist 
for simple items 
click captured through:

```
   @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();
     switch(id){
     case R.id.settings:
     break;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code in ur main activity

```
  @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, proShearch.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,2);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement this along with your activity

```
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

and put ClickListener like this

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and handle click like this

```
 @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
    }
```